# Ubuntu 14.04 jumps to GRUB every time!

Tags: grub2

There are two operating systems in my laptop, Windows XP and Ubuntu 14.04. Every time when I reboot the laptop, it will jump to GRUB 2.02. I can type these following commands e.g:

```
 set root=(hd0,7)
 textchainloader +1 
 boot
```

...and it will boot Ubuntu successfully. But I don't want to do it every time. I have searched the internet for solutions, but none of them can help. What should I do?  Many thanks. I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? You mean it comes up to the grub command console, rather than the menu?

Comment: Also, do you have os-prober installed...?

Comment: OK, are you trying to make laptop boot into Ubuntu every time you press power button ? or do you want to see a menu that lets you select windows or Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

Boot into ubuntu like you do then open terminal (ctrl+Alt+T) and type the command

sudo update-grub

reboot.

Comment: Um, you're saying to update grub without making changes to configuration ? did i get this right ?

Comment: @Xieerqi yes, it will detect the any os available and reconfigure the grub.cfg file.